# Increasing Partition or deleting Ubuntu dual boot Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssh

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for some time, though it is the first Linux system I installed on my own.  I need to increase my partition size.  It is full and I cannot run Chrome, get updates. I can pretty much only run Terminal to SSH to school servers.  I have tried to change the boot order in Grub but it does not work. I know I can run Gparted on a USB boot and increase it but I cannot get it to load. I also know that I can use windows using dual boot repair but that hasn't worked and everything else I have found online has not worked thus far.  I am dual-booting alongside Windows 10.  For the time being I am using putty but it just isn't the same.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you access your computer's built-in boot manager is very much a computer-specific thing. With most computers, you do it by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key (usually a high-numbered one, like F8 or F10) at boot time, *before* GRUB has loaded. Chances are you used this same keystroke to get the Ubuntu installer to boot. Sometimes that stops working or is disabled, though, in which case you need a workaround. Some possibilities for this include:

- **Keep trying** -- Sometimes the keystroke used to access the boot manager is finicky, in which case you might need to try it several times before you can get it to work. This is even worse if you don't know what keystroke it is. Try checking your manual, looking for messages at boot time, or asking on a forum for your computer or motherboard to learn what keystroke you should be using.
- **Reset the firmware to the defaults** -- You may be able to boot into the firmware setup utility by typing `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` in Ubuntu or by using another key sequence at boot time. You can then select an option to reset the firmware options to their defaults. This will usually re-enable the keystroke to access the boot manager. Unfortunately, it's also likely to remove the `ubuntu` boot entry you use to boot Ubuntu, so you'll need to restore it with Boot Repair, `efibootmgr`, or some other tool.
- **Disable "fast start" in the firmware** -- Some EFIs have a feature called "fast start" or something similar, which disables full USB initialization, thus cutting off access to external media. If you can get to the built-in boot manager but it doesn't show your USB drive, disabling the EFI's fast start feature can help. Note that the name of this feature is not standardized, so you may have to go hunting. Sometimes it's referred to as a level of USB initialization, in which case you'd set it to full USB initialization. Note also that this feature is unrelated to the Windows Fast Startup feature, which has an entirely different effect.
- **Install rEFInd** -- My [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) should show options for booting external media, although sometimes they appear only after you hit the Esc key in the rEFInd menu. Installing rEFInd to your hard disk, though, means that it will take over as the default boot manager from GRUB, which you might not want. Even if you prefer to keep using GRUB, you might consider installing rEFInd, then [uninstall it](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#uninstalling) or set GRUB/`ubuntu` back to the default position using `efibootmgr`'s `-o` option once you've done what you need to do with rEFInd.

Comment: Thanks, I'm an idiot and wasn't actually accessing my bootloader. I was doing it through GRUB so it wasn't actually changing anything at all. A learning experience to say the least. Thank you for your input